# init model with web api: iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, block

I am writing a pure MVC code, in which I have to call api in my model. I want to initialise my model with api. Below is the code what I am doing

[image]

But I am getting this error. Here is a code for my WSManager's api method

```
func requestWSCall(strWSName: String,method:WSHttpMethod,params : [String : Any], success:@escaping wsSuccessBlock, failure:@escaping wsFailureBlock) {

    //append WSName in base url
    var combineUrl = Constants.NetworkingUrl.baseUrl + strWSName

    var urlRequest:URLRequest

    //if method is get append param in url
    if method == .get {

        if params.count > 0 {
            combineUrl = combineUrl + params.queryString
        }
        guard let url = NSURL(string:combineUrl) else {
            return
        }
        urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

    }
        //else send param in http body
    else
    {
        guard let url = NSURL(string:combineUrl) else {
            return
        }
        urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        let parameter = params.postString

        urlRequest.httpBody = parameter.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

    }

    //header
    //        urlRequest.setValue(UIDevice.current.systemVersion, forHTTPHeaderField:  Constants.Kstring.deviceVersion)
    //        urlRequest.setValue(Constants.AppIdentity.appVersion ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField:  Constants.Kstring.appVersion)
    //        urlRequest.setValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField:  Constants.Kstring.deviceType)
    //        let strDeviceToken =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:Constants.Kstring.deviceToken)
    //        if (strDeviceToken != nil) {
    //              urlRequest.setValue(strDeviceToken, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.Kstring.deviceToken)
    //        }else{
    //             urlRequest.setValue(Constants.Kstring.emptyString, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.Kstring.deviceToken)
    //        }


    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        var valuePrint = [String:Any]()
        if method == WSHttpMethod.get {
            valuePrint["combineUrl"] = combineUrl
        }
        valuePrint["httpMethod"] = method
        valuePrint["param"] = params

        guard error == nil, let json = self.jsonSerializationWithData(data: data)
            else {
                var code = NSURLErrorUnknown

                if  error != nil {
                    code = (error! as NSError).code
                }

                let msg = self.prepareErrorResponce(code: code)
                valuePrint["error"] = WSError(msg: msg, code: code, type: .server)
                valuePrint["response"] = nil
                debugPrint(valuePrint)
                failure(WSError(msg: msg, code: code, type: .server))
                return
        }

        valuePrint["response"] = json
        valuePrint["error"] = nil
        debugPrint(valuePrint)

        if (json["status"] as! String == "success") {

            success(WSResult(data: data!, value: json))
            return

        } else {

            var msg = ""
            if json["message"] is String {
                msg = json["message"] as! String
            }
            else{
                msg = "Something went wrong"
            }

            failure(WSError(msg: msg, code: 0, type: .api))

            return
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: It's because you are doing a `try` unhandled: `self = try JSONDecoder()...`. So that piece of code can throws an error, but the closure signature doesn't. The error isn't managed. That's why. Not related, but an init with async? Might not work as you think it is.

Comment: Not related but avoid NSStuff when possible: `guard let url = NSURL(string:combineUrl) else {` => ` guard let url = URL(string:combineUrl) else {`, that would save you also the next cast `url as URL`.